# Progress Bar updating in chuncks not with each change

Tags: javascript, php

I have a working progress bar that tracks the progress of the creation of graphs created in a call to an Rscript.
Although I "update" the progress bar after each Rscript call, the progress bar moves in groups of 10 to 15 units instead of 1 at a time.
I tried "flush()" after each call, but did not help.
Is there a way to get the progress bar to behave the way I want?
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<div id="bars" align="center">
  <div align="left" id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid  #0066cc;"></div>
  <!-- Progress information -->
  <div id="information" align="center" style="width"></div>        
</div>

<?PHP
$mid=0 ;
$lastone=250 ;
$i=1 ;
while ($i <=$lastone){
  $fname='test'.$i ;
  $cmdline='Rscript R/testscript.R' ;
  exec ($cmdline) ;
  $mid ++ ;
  // update progress bar
  $percent=$mid/$lastone*100 ;
  $percent=intval($mid/$lastone *100)."%" ;
   echo '<script language="javascript">
       document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="
       <div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#0066CC;\">&nbsp;
   </div>";
   document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$mid.' Graphs processed.";
</script>'; 
flush() ;          
$i ++ ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know with at least internet explorer you need to send a large amount of data at the beginning (about 1K should do) - this may also fix up other browsers - been a while since I've done this sort of thing

I added a `flush()` before the while loop too

I also took the opportunity to rewrite the code in a way I think is easier to use, you don't have to do it that way, just add the junk comment as a HTML comment `<!-- **** etc -->` instead

```
<div id="bars" align="center">
  <div align="left" id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid  #0066cc;">
    <div id="prog" style="width:0;background-color:#0066CC;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="information" align="center" style="width"></div>        
</div>
<script>
    // this large amount of pointless text usually circumvents buffering in internet explorer at least
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************
    // ****************************************************************************************************************************************

    function updateProgress(p, m) {
        document.getElementById('prog').style.width=p+'%';
        document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = m + ' Graphs processed.';
    }
</script>
<?PHP
    flush();
    $mid=0;
    $lastone=250;
    $i=1;
    while ($i <= $lastone) {
        $fname='test'.$i;
        $cmdline='Rscript R/testscript.R';
        exec ($cmdline);
        $mid ++;
        // update progress bar
        // $percent=$mid/$lastone * 100;
        $percent=intval(100 * $mid / $lastone);
        echo '<script>updateProgress('.$percent.', '.$mid.');</script>';
        flush();
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have output buffering enabled. Therefore calling to `flush` just sends awaiting output data but does not flush the output buffer itself.

Try to add [ob_flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) before each `flush()`